# Cordova crosswalk -- App installs but immediately crashes

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime

not sure what's going on. I followed the guide exactly to use the ARM crosswalk for my application and it installs successfully but immediately crashes. I did a fresh install of the Android platform before following the crosswalk-cordova migration guide to no avail. I removed all my plugins also. Is there a way I can use logcat to see what's causing the crash? I'm using Intellij 14 if that makes any difference.

The crash is the standard `Unfortunately, APP has stopped.` message.

Any help would be appreciated!

edit: yes I have added the permissions in the android manifest file also :-(

Comment: did you try using the x86 version? I also had this problem before but it worked as soon as I used the other compiled apk. in my case it was the ARM version that I needed instead of the x86 one.

Comment: Use Android Device Monitor to see the logs.  You can add a filter for just your app or you'll see logs of every running process.

Comment: see also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329874/crosswalk-crashes-visual-studio-android-emulator/35388305#35388305